ms graph api send attachment in a chat message
I'm trying to send attachment in a teams chat message. For this purpose I use one drive to upload the file. Here is my code
async function uploadAttachment(client: Client, folderId: string, filePath: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
try {
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, filePath);
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const fileUploadPath = `/me/drive/items/${folderId}:/${fileName}:/content`;
    const response = await client.api(fileUploadPath).put(fileContent);

    return response.id; // Attachment ID
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading attachment:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to upload attachment');
}
}

async function sendMessageWithAttachment(client: Client, chatId: string, message: string, attachmentId: string, fileName: string, folderId : string): Promise<void> {
try {
    const fileUploadPath = `me/drive/items/${attachmentId}/content`;
    const contentUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/${fileUploadPath}`;
    console.log(contentUrl);

    const response = await client.api(contentUrl).get();

    await client.api(`/chats/${chatId}/messages`)
        .post({
            body: {
                contentType: 'html',  
                content: `Here is the attachment:<br><attachment id="${attachmentId}"></attachment>`
            },
            attachments: [
                {
                    id: attachmentId, 
                    name: fileName,
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg', 
                    contentUrl: contentUrl
                }
            ]
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending message with attachment:', error);
}
}

I execute these 2 functions one after another. I see my file is uploaded in One Drive, I see I can download it via graph API with no problems. But the code that has to send it in a chat returns
Error sending message with attachment: GraphError: Attachment content is null or empty for attachment with id '01JYDXTRKHQ3VR42FKZNFLHMUPHV6IE6DQ'.
Maybe I'm not using the post message api right. Can anyone help?
full error log follows:
statusCode: 400,
  code: 'BadRequest',
  requestId: '8d90f3fa-399e-4812-8e57-2c43b99496b8',
  date: 2024-08-16T10:14:51.000Z,
  body: `{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Attachment content is null or empty for attachment with id '01JYDXTRKHQ3VR42FKZNFLHMUPHV6IE6DQ'.","innerError":{"date":"2024-08-16T10:14:51","request-id":"8d90f3fa-399e-4812-8e57-2c43b99496b8","client-request-id":"9f5bdb88-8cb9-cb0a-bd68-830fd01e3c79"}}`,
  headers: Headers {
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
    'request-id': '8d90f3fa-399e-4812-8e57-2c43b99496b8',
    'client-request-id': '9f5bdb88-8cb9-cb0a-bd68-830fd01e3c79',
    'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Switzerland North","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"ZR2PEPF000001F3"}}',
    date: 'Fri, 16 Aug 2024 10:14:51 GMT'
  }
}


Does the error in your catch block contain the full response body? If so, share it - it will contain important details.
